# How do I link to pdfs in Vue when the pdf path is stored in a variable?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I am using Vue for the first time, and I can't figure out how to get my pdfs to link properly. 
This is how I am storing the data in my state.js file,

```
{
  isVideo: false,
  thumbnail: require('@/assets/images/folder/image.jpg'),
  link: '@/assets/pdfs/folder/download.pdf',
  assetTitle: 'This is a Title',
  assetCopy: 'This is copy',
  isGated: false
}
```

When I try to link to that link variable that has the url it doesn't render it properly, and it thinks that I want the url to be sitename.com/@/assets/pdfs/folder/download.pdf. I had the same problem with the images but I fixed that by adding the require() around them, however when I try to add the require() around the pdfs it says it can't find them.

also, here is my code in the .vue file that calls the pdf and image

```
<a v-bind:href="asset.link" class="test" target="_blank"><img v-bind:src="asset.thumbnail" /></a>
```

Do any of y'all know what I need to change to make this work?

Comment: Have you tried without the `@` : `link: '/assets/pdfs/folder/download.pdf'` or `link: require('/assets/pdfs/folder/download.pdf')` ?